# Setting Configuration in init.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am working in rails 2. I am developing a plugin of redmine. I want to do this in init.rb file of plugin. which i am doing in development.rb of redmine.

```
config.to_prepare do
  load 'user_patch.rb'
end
```

How can i do this in plugin init.rb?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify `development.rb`.

In `$REDMINE_ROOT/plugins/your_plugin_name/init.rb`:

```
Dispatcher.to_prepare :your_plugin_name do
  require 'user_patch'
end
```

Have a look at the [Redmine wiki](http://www.redmine.org/boards/3/topics/31445#Overriding-models-controllers-and-helpers).